# Other way for Jsoup.connect().get to prevent UI blocking

Tags: jsoup, android

I'm running the Jsoup.connect().get in an Asynctask to prevent network on main thread but this method also blocks the UI because of the get(). Any suggestions to prevent or maybe minimize the blocking?

```
@Override
protected Document doInBackground(String... strings) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: the code looks fine. what do you mean by minimize.

Comment: yes it works fine but I would like to eliminate the UI blocking because it freezes my application, even my progressbar stops

Comment: how do you invoke asynctask. the issue may be some where else. Asynctask is asynchronous

Comment: task.execute(url).get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments you have

```
 task.execute(url).get();
```

to

```
task.execute(url);
```

Calling `get` does not make it Asynchronous any more. It will wait for the result blocking the ui thread. Just use `.execute`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
public final Result get ()

Added in API level 3
Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Returns
The computed result.
```

Comment: I got it, Ill just transfer my methods to the task.. thanks, ill accept this answer in 8 mins

Comment: @DanielGomez i din't understand transfer the methods??

Comment: I was using Document doc = task.execute(url).get(); and do something with the doc (outside the asynctask) I need to put them inside so I can remove the get()

Comment: @DanielGomez you mean you want the result in activity . then use interface as a call back to the activity. i meant updating ui